# Finding the double integral when the boundaries for y is not specified

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

A question in my Calculus book states:

"Find the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the cylinder $z=9-y^2$ and the plane $x=2$"

When this answer was being covered in class, it was decided that the double integral to find this should be:

$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{2} 9-y^2 dxdy $

The process I understand well, but I am not quite following 'why' or 'how' the boundaries for the integral for $y$ was determined.

In my notes I have written:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
0 &=9-y^2 \\ 
y^2&=9\\ 
y&=3 
\end{aligned}  
$$

But this still doesn't seem quite clear to me as to why it is done. Why is z set to 0 to get this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about the graphs of these?  In the yz- plane, z= 9- y^2 is a parabola with vertex at y= 0, z= 9 opening downward.  Since there is no "x" in the formula, x can be anything so that is a parbolic **cylinder** extending infinitely along the x- axis.  Since this is in the first quadrant, the planes x= 0 and z= 0 are part of the boundary and we are told that x= 2 is a boundary.
    Since one boundary is z= 0, that will intersect the cylinder z= 9- y^2 where 0= 9- y^2.  That is the equation you have which gives them y= 3 and y= -3.  The cylinder cuts the plane z= 0 in those two lines, extended parallel to the x- axis.  So the projection of the cylinder into its base, the z= 0 plane, is the rectangle bounded by the lines x= 0, x= 2, y= 3, and y= -1.  That is the region you integrate over.